# what are the appropriate prepositions for this case? python, termial, ubuntu, vmware, MacOS

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

I am running a wmware on my Mac.

the host OS is MacOS, the guest OS is ubuntu.

I am running a python script in terminal the guest OS (ubuntu).

should I say, I am running a python script in the terminal of guest ubuntu in vmware on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> I'm running a python script in the terminal of an ubuntu VM, which runs[is running] in VMWare on a MacOS machine.

If the flavour of virtual environment and the Host OS are not important (ie they have no bearing on what you are explaining) you could even shorten this to:

> I'm running a python script in the terminal of an ubuntu VM

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it seems that `an ubuntu VM` and `VMWare` are redundant?

Comment: not necessarily - You could be running Hyper-V or XenServer. If the flavour of virtual environment is not important, you could omit it. Same could be said for the Host OS

Comment: The other information might be important if you were asking someone for technical support though...